# How would I go about allowing multiple instances of a TTS app to run?

Tags: c++, command-line, text-to-speech, sapi

For a project, I have been looking through the web for a MS command line program to read text to speech out loud with a custom SAPI5 voice. I found one that suits my needs, https://github.com/brookhong/tts. This is what I was looking for, but the thing that I needed was for it to run multiple times at once. I have `tts -f 3 -v 1 "Hello"` in a batch file, and it works just the way I want it but running the file a second time will cause it to just talk after the first instance has completed talking.

I have tried removing `m_pVoice->WaitUntilDone( INFINITE );` from the source and reducing INFINITE to 1, as that seems to prevent the second instance from playing. What would be another way to go about this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the source of the github repository you linked, there's a call

```
hr = pVoice->Speak(wbuf, 0, NULL);
```

Which could be the hold up. Instead of 0 you might want to try changing that to

```
hr = pVoice->Speak(wbuf, SPF_ASYNC , NULL);
```

Recompile, and then try running multiple instances.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the long wait.

Comment: It seems like since you're running this as an executable, you'd just use a batch script or run multiple terminals.